# Perfomance Issue using selectAll in ie8 and ie9

Tags: d3.js, raphael

We are using selectAll function in  this we are passing data to plot  objects . Data contains array of 2000 elements while plotting this it's taking so much time in ie8 and while loading it ask to stop the script.

We are using d34raphael to give it functionality like d3.

for ex.

```
var raphael = new Raphael(document.body,0,0);
var d3_raphael = d3.raphael(raphael);

var svg = d3_raphael.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width",1000)
.attr("height",600);


svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(Data)
.enter()
.append("circle")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you're using `.selectAll()`, the problem is that you're drawing 2000 elements at once. This isn't a D3/Raphael issue either, but simply the time it takes IE to render the page.

You could try loading only part of the data to start with to prevent the browser from locking up if that's possible. Beyond that, there's nothing you can really do.

Comment: I got it but  can  you tell me how can i load part of data and than  other. an example will be appreciated.

Comment: This really depends on your particular application. I can't tell you what data you need to start with. You might want to have a look at [crossfilter](http://square.github.io/crossfilter/) to get started.